# French language not showing url alias path

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have installed multilingual module and added french country for this.

Added one content with English & french.

English & French text showing fine for this content (using block region

But after mouse hove to english & french, in english url alias path showing, but in french url alias not showing.

How to rid this in D7?